# Issue in Connecting SSIS to PostgreSQL (via OLEDB)

Tags: postgresql, ssis

I'm working on a Project, where I have to create SSIS Package for the Data Migration. I'm using PostgreSQL for the database connectivity. Initially, I was using ODBC driver to connect SSIS Project to PostgreSQL, later on, I found that ODBC doesn't support transactions for rolling back previous transactions(insertion, deletion, updating etc) if any failure occurs. Now, I was required to use OLEDB for database connectivity.

On Googling, I came to know about two OLEDB providers for PostgreSQL, which are :

- http://pgfoundry.org/projects/oledb/ - OPEN SOURCE
- http://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/component/filecab... - COMMERCIAL

First One, which is Open Source, is not at all working. Its Last Update was in 2006, So I don't think they are planning to update it to make it work with SSIS.

Second One, which is commercial, is working. I tried the Trial Version and I must say this provider is awesome. But, they are charging too much for the full version.

Please provide any workaround for achieving this(Connecting SSIS to PostgreSQL with full Support of Transactions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I found the solution. We can select ODBC provider under the option of .Net Provider from the dropdown at the time of creating new Ado.Net connection.

I wonder how this ODBC driver is supporting transactions even though everywhere it is mentioned that ODBC doesn’t support transactions.
Atleast, I got it working. Cheers!!