# Is there any way to connect to PostgreSQL13 in OLEDB Command in SSIS. I have found NpgSQL but I don't see in the list of OLE connections

Tags: ssis, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, postgresql-13

Though I have installed ODBC drivers for PostgreSQL as well as NpgSQL I can see them in server explorer of Visual 2019, but not in the list of OLEDB available connections as shown in the figure. What steps should I take to achieve PostgreSQL Connection in the list shown below.
[image]

Images of ODBC / Server Explorer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using the oledb source which wont work with ODBC drivers, make sure you use the ODBC data source component if you are going to be using ODBC drivers

[image: Data Sources]

Comment: I do not want to connect through ODBC as I cannot use oledbcommand component of SSIS which is required for updating the records in-case they are found with change in field values. This I cannot achieve with ODBC Destination component.

Comment: The only oledb drivers for Postgresql I know of is commercial but they do offer a trial.

Comment: Alternatively have you tried creating an ADO.NET and setting the ADO.NET provider to ODBC? This article mentions that it might have limited transaction support,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638897/issue-in-connecting-ssis-to-postgresql-via-oledb

Comment: When I try ADO.Net With ODBC I get the following error : [ADO NET Source [2]] Error: ADO NET Source has failed to acquire the connection {F994A17D-ADBE-4F9E-830C-4F7ED9E35257} with the following error message: "ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

Comment: I am not using ODBC to connect to OLEDB.